Any way to use CIO in Ktor for Compose Multiplatform?
Currently developing Compose Multiplatform with ktor. I tried to use ktor-client-cio dependency, but it throws error.
libs.versions.toml:
ktor = "2.3.10"
ktor-wasm = "3.2.0"

ktor-client-cio = { group = "io.ktor", name = "ktor-client-cio", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-contentNegotiation = { group = "io.ktor", name = "ktor-client-content-negotiation", version.ref = "ktor-wasm" }


[bundles]
ktor-client = ["ktor-client-core", "ktor-client-cio" /* ... */]
# ...

error logs:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':composeApp:wasmJsCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:2.3.10.
  Required by:
      project :composeApp
   > No matching variant of io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:2.3.10 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during 'kotlin-api', preferably optimized for non-jvm, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target' with value 'js' but:
       - Variant 'iosArm64ApiElements-published' capability io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:2.3.10 declares a library for use during 'kotlin-api':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'native' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'wasm'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for non-jvm)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.wasm.target (required 'js')
...

build.gradle.kts of project:
@file:Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")

rootProject.name = "gum"
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/kotlin/p/wasm/experimental")
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/kotlin/p/wasm/experimental")
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}

include(":composeApp")
include(":server")
include(":shared")

build.gradle.kts of composeApp:
kotlin {

  /* ... */

    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting

        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
            implementation(libs.koin.android)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
        }

        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.animation)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(projects.shared)
            implementation(libs.precompose)
            implementation(libs.precompose.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.precompose.koin)
            implementation(libs.uuid)

            implementation(libs.koin)
            implementation(libs.koin.compose)

            implementation(libs.coil)
            implementation(libs.coil.compose)
            implementation(libs.coil.network.ktor)

            implementation(libs.bundles.ktor.client)
        }

        iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
        }

        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.cio)
        }
    }
}


Could you please share the build.gradle.kts from the composeApp subproject to help you give you the right code?

shared! please check the last snippet

The CIO engine isn't implemented for the WASM target, so you get the error. For the WASM target you can use the io.ktor:ktor-client-core:3.0.0-wasm2 artifact from the https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/kotlin/p/wasm/experimental repository.
